# While reading excel row value it ignores decimal values like I have 25.44 but it returns only 25

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Text;IMEX=2;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited""); /*for office 2003 connection*/
conn.Open();

string strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" + Table + "]";
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strQuery, conn);
System.Data.DataTable ExcelToDataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();
adapter.Fill(ExcelToDataTable);
```

I want to read as 45.4 not only 45.

Comment: please write the code in code snippets by pressing ctrl+K on highlighted code. and please clarify the question more.

Comment: Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: It sounds like it is being truncated somewhere

Comment: Hi everyone , Thanks for your replay, I resolved it by using third party DLL.